# I ViewUI Vue.js show more expanding component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It's used on all the demos, the clickable blurred expand/collapse button.  Is there a component for doing this for you or a demo that shows the code/styles used to do it?  Would figure since they use it for all their demos and they have variations of it, they must have one in there.
https://www.iviewui.com/components/card-en

[image: Downwards expanding button]

I'm hoping there's a wrapper component that does it for you.  The blurring effect and the auto-expanding button.  I've had to implement my own by hooking into the element and using scrollHeight/clientHeight.  Hoping for a component that does the blurring and expansion for you.  I'm open to other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own using $refs and checking scrollHeight and clientHeight.